# Best practices for finding objects from a list of ids?

Tags: mongodb, morphia, nosql

I need to retrieve all documents associated with a list of ids.

I thought of a couple of ways to do it:

- Use a filter, then add a `or` clause and for each id add a `id equals x` condition to that or.
- Use the `in` operator, like `query.field("_id").in(ids)`
- something else?

Is there a method considered to be a best practice for this kind of case?

Also, which method performs best in large data sets?

Comment: Since the `_id` field is indexed by default. You can use the `$in` operator to get the documents from a list of given ids. If would fare better than using the `$or` operator.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).